# Recurring contributions no longer showing Custom Fields in subsequent contributions

Tags: recurring-contributions, iatspayments

Drupal 7.69
CiviCRM 5.20.0
iATSPayments 1.7

Around the end of Nov 2019 we updated to Civi 5.20 and at the same time we moved to a new server. Since then our recurring series are not including the custom fields from the first contribution. Would this be related to an improper cron setup after the server move or would it be related to the CiviCrm update?

Answer (score 1):

How contributions are created as part of a recurring series is not well-defined by CiviCRM core, it depends on the payment processor.

iATS Payments will create the new contribution in the recurring sequence based on a combination of:
1. the settings in the recurring record and 
2. it's best guess of a previous contribution to use as a template (i.e. the most recent contribution in the sequence that has a matching amount).

The code that generates the contributions and payments is here: https://github.com/iATSPayments/com.iatspayments.civicrm/blob/master/api/v3/Job/Iatsrecurringcontributions.php

So either it's not finding the right contribution to use as a template, or in your case, since it's an issue with all recurring contributions, I suspect it's a code issue, worth posting to the iATS extension issue queue, here:

https://github.com/iATSPayments/com.iatspayments.civicrm/issues